# YTPlayerView not found issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, youtube-api, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

Currently i have kinda strange issue with [YTPLayerView](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper). I already have a project that contains both Objective-C and Swift codes. So, I need to use Youtube Player in Objective-c. The problem is that when i declare my Objective-c View Controller in Bridging-Header my Objective-C header file fives an error "'YTPlayerView.h' file not found", but this error do not occurs when my Bridging header is empty. Maybe i forgot something to include idk. Can someone help me?
This is my Bridging Header code:

```
#import "CameraViewController.h";
```

This is my CameraViewController.h file:

```
@import UIKit;
#import "YTPlayerView.h"

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController<YTPlayerViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;

@end
```

I have already installed the podfile for youtube player:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.4'

end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do:

```
#import <youtube_ios_player_helper/YTPlayerView.h>
```